# Is post query permission checks possible with solr?

Tags: alfresco

We have in one of our customisations implemented permission checks with dynamic authorities in Alfresco. When migrating to solr the search results for those nodes affected by our dynamic permissions became faulty. The reason seems to be that permission checks are done at query time, however our dynamic permissions are not taken into account :(

Here is a short explanations of how our dynamic authorities work:

Check if a node has an association to an authority, if the current user belongs to that authority (group) -> approve access. The node has a lot of different associations and everyone is checked and given READ or WRITE access depending on to which association it belongs.

Is there anyway to tell the Search service to do permission checking on the returned nodes instead (like lucene does)? One workaround I thought of would be to run the query as administrator, then iterate over the result and manually do the permission checks?

Could that be a way to solve it? Any other ideas you could share with me?

Answer (score 4):

Alfresco will perform after-query permission checks on SOLR results when the `security.anyDenyDenies` property is set to `true`. This check will involve any dynamic authorities, i.e. it will be a standard check.
The main problem then would be to get the full results from SOLR without pre-filtering there. Other than setting the runAs user to `System` in a custom sub-class of `org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrQueryLanguage` (within / around `super.executeQuery` method call - bean(s) `search.lucene.alfresco`, `search.solr.alfresco`, `search.fts.alfresco.index` and `search.solr.cmis` in `solr-search-context.xml`), I see no simpler way to achieve this.

Note: This applies to Alfresco 4.2d and later - I don't know when after-query permissions for SOLR have actually been introduced, but they weren't present when 4.0 came out AFAIK.

Comment: In solrcore.properties there is a property ```alfresco.doPermissionChecks=true```
. I wonder what happens it one has anyDenyDenies set to true and that property set to false? Will it then perform post query checks?

Comment: That might actually work - I have never tried to fiddle with that property myself and forgot about it when writing the answer...
Edit: Checked the code in `SolrAuthoritySetScorer` and it does trigger the inclusion of all index leaves in the result when set to false.

Comment: OK, so to sum it up, the answer to the question is: a) `security.anyDenyDenies` (in Alfresco properties) is `true` by default, so leave it that way, b) set `alfresco.doPermissionChecks` (in solrcore.properties inside a given Solr config subfolder) to `false`. (Tested successfully with Alfresco 5.2.)

Comment: Note: Some versions of ACS 5.2 and all the more recent versions require setting `security.postProcessDenies=true` via global properties as well. An OR-ed condition has been added to ACS code for determination whether SOLR result can be used as-is, and without that setting, it skips post-filtering, as SOLR states it "has checked denies" even when its permission checking has been disabled (they forgot to do a combined check of a config and a request property before setting a flag in the response).